# How can I make iPhone clock alarms obey vibrate-only mode?

Tags: iphone, alarm

In the Clock app, if I use a timer or alarm that goes off while my iPhone is on vibrate mode, the alarm sound still goes off.  Is there a way to make it obey the vibrate mode?  Or a way to tell it whether or not to ignore it?

Comment: Given the confusion below, you may want to clarify the title ("Make iPhone clock alarm...")

Comment: I set alarms all the time, and sometimes miss them because I leave my phone on vibrate instead of sound lol. With the Timer, I'm not sure that's an option, but Alarm should obey the vibrate on/off switch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calendar alarms obey the mute switch.  Clock alarms do not.

Personally, I consider this a feature and not a bug--but I can understand why you'd at least want the option.

However, short of jailbreaking, there is currently no way to change this behavior in the Apple-provided applications.

Comment: Fore sure it is a feature as it is explained in the manual exactly like you write it above.

Answer (score 9):

Create a silent ringtone (e.g. a [short piece of silence](http://www.patom.ch/pics/5_seconds_of_silence.m4r) in Garage Band or the ringtone creator of your choice) and set that as the sound for the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a different alarm clock app such as [Awaken](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/awaken/id327767743?at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow&mt=8&uo=4) or [Alarm Clock Pro](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-pro/id335678373?mt=8&at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow).

These apps WILL obey the iPhones vibrate setting (I think). Even if they don't, they will still let you customize the ringtone of your alarms to make them quieter...