# iPhone calendar alerts are not muted when vibrate switch is on

Tags: iphone

I leave my iPhone in vibrate mode all the time.  The switch still works (when I switch it the iPhone shows the ringer on/off notice).

This morning it started alerting me for calendar alerts with both vibration and audible chimes. Note that I'm NOT talking about clock/timer alarms.

I've rebooted the iPhone, and it's still alerting me both ways.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A firmware update resolved the issue for me.  I'm not sure if something became corrupted, or if a setting had changed inadvertently, but it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar alert is something that you asked for so will not be suppressed by the Silent switch. According to the HIG the switch is supposed to indicate that you do not wish to hear *unsolicited* sounds such as incoming call ringtones.

Comment: Interesting.  It never made a noise before, why would it start today?  Further, [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/make-iphone-clock-alarms-obey-vibrate-only-mode/1661#1661) suggests that the calendar alarms *do* obey the silent switch...